# How to call the IApplicationBuilder object in ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core, and I am now building a ASP.NET Core MVC app that requests data from another API using authentication bearer header. I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#bearer-token). But I am confused where should I put the following code block

```
var scopes = new[] {$"api://.../access_as_user"};
var result = await app.AcquireToken(scopes)
                      .ExecuteAsync();

httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

// Call the web API.
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiUri);
```

Should I put it in Startup.cs or in the controller? If I put it in controller I get error: "cannot use local variable or local function 'app' declared in top-level statement in this context".

This is my `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAd")
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
            .AddDownstreamApi("MyApi", Configuration.GetSection("GraphBeta"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        services.AddRazorPages()
             .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    const string scopeRequiredByApi = "user_impersonation";

    public static string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}";

    // SurfViewer cliendId
    public static string ClientId = "{my_clientId}";

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [RequiredScope(scopeRequiredByApi)]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync()
    {
        var scopes = new[] { $"api://{my_clientId}/user_impersonation" };
        var result = await app.AcquireToken(scopes)
                              .ExecuteAsync();

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        // Call the web API.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("{source url}");

        return response;
    }

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Cannot use local variable or local function 'app' declared in top-level statement in this context

How should I request a access token in the controller and make an http request?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you shared means your api is protected by Azure AD so that you need an access token in your MVC project to call the web api. To generate the access token in your MVC project, what you had in the startup.cs is correct. And then you could use `TokenAcquisition` to generate your access token.

You should put your code into controller.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ITokenAcquisition _getToken;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public HomeController(
        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
        ITokenAcquisition getToken)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        _getToken = getToken;
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy()
    {
        var token = await _getToken.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync((new string[] { "api://xxx/Tiny.Read" }));
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api_url")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ token}
            }
        };

        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        var res = "";
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(res);
            var xxx = obj.value;
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

my test result.

[image]

Comment: I was able to get access token injecting dependency IAuthenticationHeaderProvider, and I could make successfull http call with this access token. However, when I try to get token and make http call in httpost action method, I am getting 403 error.

Comment: 403 then you might check the token scp or roles claims to see if the token contained the correct api permission.